# Luma theme Magento 2 and promo label

Tags: css, magento2

I am trying to copy the default home page from the demo shop with Luma theme. 
Using  a demo store where the homepage looks like this:

[image]

I have then copied the image over and on my clean installation of Magento running same theme (Luma) and copying the below html code from the demo store.

```
<span class="content bg-white">
    <span class="info">New Luma Yoga Collection</span>
    <strong class="title">Get fit and look fab in new seasonal          styles</strong> 
    <span class="action more button">Shop New Yoga</span>
</span>
```

But when I test then I do not get the label on the image as above. It looks like this still:

[image]

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You also need to copy CSS from the theme as well. Without that, it won't work properly.

Comment: So the Luma theme is different from a fresh install and from the demo store. I though the CSS would be the same, thanks I will give it a go....

Comment: Yes, luma theme is different from demo store. Because in the demo store they have made some changes based on their requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Luma Theme as your parent theme in the declaration of your demo theme and you will get all the styles from Luma without the need of copying them.